# iOS 17 Beta: Location Permissions Reset After Upgrade - Beta Issue or New Change?

Tags: ios, beta, ios17

I had a variety of location permissions set on iOS 16, ranging from "**Once**" and "**WhileInUse**" to "**Always**" for some apps. However, after upgrading to iOS 17 Beta, all the location permissions were reset. Now, every app prompts for permission as if its status was "**Not Determined**."

Is this behavior specific to the beta version, or is it a new change introduced by Apple in iOS 17?